# cakePHP 2.0.6 - validations

Tags: cakephp-2.0

I am using cakePHP 2.0.6 and I am trying to add validation for fields like name, title shoudl not be blank. I placed logic inside model class.

```
<?php
```

class Post extends AppModel {
    public $name = 'Post';

```
public $validate = array(
    'name' => array(
        'required' => true
    ),
    'title' => array(
        'required' => true
    )
);
```

}

but somehow it is not working, Can I have some help please?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to add some more attributes like

```
<?php
 class Post extends AppModel {

   public $name = 'Post';

   public $validate = array(
     'name' => array(
     'rule' => 'notEmpty',
     'required' => true,
     'message'  => 'Name Should not be blank'
   ),
   'title' => array(
     'rule' => 'notEmpty',
     'required' => true,
     'message'  => 'Title Should not be blank'
   )
  );
}
```

Please let me know if this isn't work

Comment: Thanks for your quick help, now I know the problem and what I missed.